# How to inject Global implementation in AngularClass/angular-starter?

Tags: angular, webpack

This questions is related to [AngularClass/angular-starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter)

I'd like to have possibility to define API URL by setting env variable (so I can configure it on build platform).

I looked [here](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter/blob/master/config/webpack.prod.js#L157-L173) and found out that it can be done with *DefinePlugin*.

I added `API` global variable in `webpack.prod|dev.js` and some other places

```
// Webpack.js
const API = process.env.API || "http://localhost/api";

new DefinePlugin({
   ...
   'API': METADATA.API,
   'process.env': {
     ...
   }
 }),



// custom-typings.d.ts
interface GlobalEnvironment {
  ..
  API: string;
  ..
}
```

The `Global` interface inherits after `GlobalEnvironment`. I searched for any its implementation in project but with no luck.

I tried injecting it anyway, counting that some magic might happen, but it didn't.

```
@Injectable()
export class ConvertingService {
  constructor(
      private http: Http,
      private global: Global
  ) { }
```

I got an unresolved exception.

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ConvertingService: ([object Object], ?).
```

What is the proper way of injecting `Global` implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you don't need to inject anything. Just try to *use* `API` variable in your code. Imagine that `API` is global variable (it is not). Webpack overrides reference when variable is requested... See https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter/issues/386